# Using symbolic variables in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

How do I use symbolic variables in the Simulink block diagram for different blocks? I'd like to run `linmod2` and obtain a transfer function in the terms of the symbolic variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to John D'Errico, aka [woodchips](https://stackoverflow.com/users/85109/woodchips), [this likely not possible](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/284398).  That was my understanding of the way the `linmod` family of algorithms worked as well.  However, what are you trying to do that you need to get the analytic representation of the model with the symbolic parameter?  There may be other ways to accomplish what you need, please elaborate.

Comment: Nothing more than what's stated in the question ; I'm trying to obtain the transfer function from a block diagram.